# Configure VPN connection on Terminal

Tags: terminal, vpn

[How to create a VPN connection via terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128297/how-to-create-a-vpn-connection-via-terminal) explains how to use Terminal to enable a VPN connection previously configured via System Preferences. I want to go one step further and configure a VPN connection without using System Preferences. How can I do this from Terminal?

Comment: Wait this seems to be a duplicate question of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128297/how-to-create-a-vpn-connection-via-terminal. But I still would like to know if you can specify a username and password for this vpn connection

Comment: I took a look at that solution and it seems that they are simply starting an already configured vpn connection from terminal (I could be wrong here). What I want to know is how would you go about configuring a new vpn connection in terminal?