# How to set up a VPN connection via terminal?

Tags: terminal, network, automator, vpn

I found [How to create a VPN connection via terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128297/how-to-create-a-vpn-connection-via-terminal) but this isn't really what I'm looking for. I regularly have to set up new computers for new users that need to connect to our VPN and I'm trying to automate some of the setup. I need to create a L2TP over IPSec connection so I also need to put in the server address, account name, shared secret, and possibly a password. Does anyone know if this is possible with Mac systems? Or can provide some kind of script to get me in the right direction?

Comment: Would a [configuration profile](https://www.howtogeek.com/216137/create-a-configuration-profile-to-simplify-vpn-setup-on-iphones-and-ipads/) work in your situation?

Comment: I think this would work halfway. I need to be able to use it for multiple users, a profile I think would just be created for the same user. Unless there's a way to create a profile from a script and I could pass in the account name as a variable?

Comment: Profiles can be set up to apply either to a specific user, or system-wide. System-wide should do what you need.

Comment: Since profiles are just text files (xml), it‘s no problem to generate them from a script.